# Where did Finn get the blueprints for Starkiller Base?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Being that Finn was a stormtrooper and basically a janitor — he tells Han he worked sanitation — where did he get the blueprints for **Starkiller Base**?

If he was taught the schematics by the **First Order**, why would they want stormtroopers to memorize plans for their super-secret battle station? Isn't that asking for trouble?

Then again, I guess since Finn had to work sanitation, maybe stormtroopers are the **First Order**'s general purpose grunts, meaning they also have to memorize its visually accurate plans for construction purposes. Is that the canon?

Answer (score 23):

Finn didn't have the plans for the Starkiller Base. The Resistance already had them. In fact, I'm pretty sure they're being shown on the hologram display before Finn even mentions that he's an ex-stormtrooper.

The Resistance got the plans for the base the same way they got the plans for the two Death Stars: old fashioned recon/spy missions gathering the data and bringing it back.

Comment: Yes it is explained :)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield No, after learning of StarKiller base they sent a reconnaissance mission to check it out.  That's when Matt Parkman got the plans for it.

Comment: alrighty then, fixed.

Answer (score 13):

According to Alan Dean Foster's novelizations, the plans came from scans by a reconnaissance flight sent by the Resistance the moment Finn told them the base location (**correction: he told them about its existence, and I think location came from extrapolating the Hosnian system's attack vector**).

Easter egg(ish): The flight was led by "Snap" Wexley, who attentive <strike>Star Wars nerds</strike> readers will recognize as Nora Wexley's rebellious teenage son from "Aftermath" otherwise largely worthless prequel book.

> In the main conference room of the base on D’Qar, an ongoing strategy session had brought together the leaders of the Resistance. Leia, Poe, C-3PO, Han, and an assortment of senior officers including Statura and Ackbar were assembled around a three-dimensional map of an isolated, frozen planet that up until now had not been worth a hopeful visit from a minor trading ship. Finn was present, too, **since it was his information about the world in question that had prompted the gathering**.
>   “**The scan data from Captain Snap Wexley’s reconnaissance flight confirms everything Finn has told us**,” Poe announced to the group.
>   Wexley spoke up. “They’ve built a new kind of hyperspace weapon within the planet itself. Something that can fire across interstellar distances in the equivalent of real time.” His expression showed his incredulity. “I’ve had my share of technical training, but I can’t even imagine how that’s possible.”

Comment: Does this mean they received technical readouts from a reconnaissance flight? In the movie's hologram, it appears they are able to draw things that are underground.

Comment: @user339676 - ground penetrating radars exist even in modern US military, with our far inferior tech.

Comment: Haha, that is true, but doing it from space is another feat entirely even for *Star Wars*. For example, the Galactic Empire chose to deploy thousands of probe droids when searching for the Rebels instead of doing thousands of recon flights. I always assumed that meant that finding hidden areas required much more surface-level detective work than scanning whole planets from space. Then again, it has been 30 years...

Comment: @user339676 That's because probe droids are cheaper than humans who need to be trained and fed and kept alive at least long enough to report back.